# MDEP-187 error blocking the build to go through

Tags: java, jenkins, build, sonarqube

I'm working on a Java program, the build works fine (local and jenkins), but when Sonar executes the build, i get the following error :

```java
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:copy-dependencies
 (copy-dependencies) on project test-service-deploy: Artifact has not been 
packaged yet. When used on reactor artifact, copy should be executed after
 packaging: see MDEP-187. -> [Help 1]
```

Seems like it tries to get the dependency from workspace path, but doesn't find anything.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up finding the problem, and i had to disable maven workspace resolution maven, that means that the program will get the dependencies from the local repository.